# how can i find this .children of this parent category

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<select id="advert_category" name="advert_category">
<option value="">All Items</option>
<option value="512">All Test 2</option>
<option value="52">Vehicles</option>
<option value="64" data-depth="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Cars For Sale</option>
<option value="65" data-depth="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Cars For Rent</option>
<option value="66" data-depth="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;All Vehicle Spare Parts</option>
<option value="67" data-depth="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Number</option>
</select>
```

i want to toggle all subcategories under vehicles

Comment: Can you change the HTML so that the options have a parent ID like `<option value="64" data-parent_id="52">&nbsp;&nbsp;Cars For Sale</option>`?

Comment: ok yes i can ...

Comment: I tried     $(this).find('[data-depth=1]').toggle();
but its toggling all suncategories under all categories

Comment: if you can make that HTML change, then you could simply do: `$(this).find('[data-parent_id=52]').toggle();`

Comment: i am doing on select change and there are 11 categories with subcategories so need one that toggle subcategories of parent category

Comment: How about organizing your options into logical categories using `<optgroiup>`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup

Comment: it wont work like this and cant do it